# SQL - Time Series Events into Pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL table every second alarm tags gets updated from PLC.

| id | tagname | delete | value | datetime | quality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 | 0 | 1 | 28-09-2021 17:43:38.767 | 192 |
| 29 | RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 | 0 | 0 | 28-09-2021 17:44:01.723 | 192 |
| 30 | RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_5 | 0 | 1 | 28-09-2021 17:44:02.070 | 192 |
| 31 | RH.ONCHANGE.CYCLE_COMPLETE | 0 | 1 | 28-09-2021 17:44:07.637 | 192 |
| 32 | RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_5 | 0 | 0 | 28-09-2021 17:44:07.637 | 192 |
| 33 | RH.ONCHANGE.CYCLE_COMPLETE | 0 | 0 | 28-09-2021 17:44:35.513 | 192 |
| 34 | RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_1 | 0 | 0 | 28-09-2021 17:44:35.513 | 192 |
| 35 | RH.ONCHANGE.ALL_GUN_HOME | 0 | 1 | 28-09-2021 17:44:38.890 | 192 |
| 36 | RH.ONCHANGE.ALL_GUN_HOME | 0 | 0 | 28-09-2021 17:46:00.087 | 192 |
| 37 | RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_1 | 0 | 1 | 28-09-2021 17:46:01.710 | 192 |

If I had a clean data set, with no missing '1'(on) or '0' (off) events, I can achieve this with:

```
select tOn.tagname, tOn.datetime StartTime, tOff.datetime EndTime
from (
select tagname, datetime, 
      ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by tagname order by datetime) EventID
from [brakerh].[dbo].[onchange] where value = 1
) tOn
LEFT JOIN (
select tagname, datetime, 
      ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by tagname order by datetime) EventID
from [brakerh].[dbo].[onchange] where value = 0
) tOff
on (tOn.tagname = tOff.tagname and tOn.EventID = tOff.EventID)
```

| tagname | starttime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 | 28-09-2021 17:41:00.190 | 28-09-2021 17:39:57.753 |
| RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 | 28-09-2021 17:44:38.890 | 28-09-2021 17:42:30.640 |
| RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 | 28-09-2021 17:47:47.537 | 28-09-2021 17:46:00.087 |
| RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 | 28-09-2021 17:51:04.253 |  |
| RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 |  | 28-09-2021 17:52:42.467 |
| RH.ONCHANGE.PROCESS_CYCLE_4 | 28-09-2021 17:58:10.653 | 28-09-2021 17:56:29.587 |

Requirements
An efficient way of processing table to achieve my output, which handles missing '0'/'1' events (shown as the blank in the sample Output) - I use SQL Server 2008 so some functions like 'lag' doesn't work

Comment: Handle missing 0/1 events...Not sure if you can make something correct with this spec. If you have a correct-looking 1 followed by 0, how do you know there are not two records missing between?

Comment: @George Menoutis: We can just ignore that one case as its very rare. Situation 1: if '1' comes and again new '1' comes after many missing records, endtime will be null anyways . Situation 2:  if '0' comes after many missing records in that case we match with the last updated '1'. anyways i hope we have to ignore that .